# jqueryui datepicker change date with link

Tags: jquery-ui, triggers, datepicker, external, back

I would like to be able to go back one day, everytime i click a link / div.

```
<div> 2013-12-12 - clicking on this, goes back in datepicker one day at a time</div>    
<div class="datepicker1"></div>
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a complete code with example:

JS:

```
var $datepicker = $( "#datepicker" );
$datepicker.datepicker();
var date = new Date();
var newdate = new Date(date);
newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() - 7);
$datepicker.datepicker('setDate', newdate);
```

HTML:

```
<script>
function minus()
{
var $datepicker = $( "#datepicker" );
var date = $datepicker.datepicker('getDate'); 
var newdate = new Date(date);
newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() - 1);
$datepicker.datepicker('setDate', newdate);   
}    
</script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
    <a href="#" onclick="minus()">minus date</a>
```

JSFIDDLE:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/epHNZ/295/
```

Comment: your js/fiddle is not doing what he actually wants.